# How to show commands in Wordpress with an outline and grey background?

Tags: wordpress

I have seen a few blogs where the blogger would add an outline and a grey background around small one-liners commands or key presses.

For example for ALT + F2, 'ALT' and 'F2' would be displayed with an outline, a different font and a grey background to emphasize that they are keys.

How do I do this in Wordpress ?

Comment: have you tried selecting the text and then press on: "blockquote" (small quote icon) in your editor in Wordpress itself. If that is what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be down to a style set in their CSS, StackOverflow uses:

```
<kbd>Control</kbd>
```

To generate: <kbd>Control</kbd> as an example.

In Wordpress you can edit the stylesheet(s) using the [appearance editor](http://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Editor_Screen) and add something along the lines of:

```
kbd {
    padding: .1em .6em;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    color: #333;
}
```

To style the `<kbd>` elements.